# Generalized Schoenflies - formalizing step in proof?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, surgery-theory

I am currently reading [Hatcher's 3-Manifolds notes](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/3M/3Mdownloads.html), the part proving Alexander's theorem, which is a specific case of the [generalized Schoenflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem#Generalizations):

> Every smoothly embedded $S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ bounds a smooth 3-ball.

The proof seems to rely on intuition for these low-dimensional arguments, which I find disconcerting, because I have not yet developed that intuition, so I am trying to give actual formal proofs for the statements in Hatcher's proof.

The proof begins with a generic smoothly embedded closed surface $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. I have been able to prove that I can isotope $S$ so that projection on the last coordinate $\pi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a Morse function on $S$. Hatcher then argues that if $t$ is a regular value for $\pi$, then $\pi^{-1}(t)\cap S$ is a finite collection of circles.

The proof continues by taking an innermost circle $C\subset \pi^{-1}(t)\cap S$, which by 2-dimensional Schoenflies bounds a disk $D$, and $D\cap S=\partial D=C$. Hatcher then uses surgery to cut away a neighborhood of $C$ in $S$, and cap the cuts with two disks.

This last part is what I want to formalize. It seems we are finding a small-enough tubular neighborhood $C\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subset S$, and then removing that, leaving $S_-=C\times\{-\epsilon\}$ and $S_+=C\times\{\epsilon\}$. Again by 2-dimensional Schoenflies, these bound disks $D_-$ and $D_+$. What I don't get is: **why are $S_-$ and $S_+$ still innermost**? Or, put differently, **why is $D_-\cap S=S-$ (and similarly for $S_+$)**?

Intuitively, this seems obvious, and it seems like some sort of "continuity" argument would work, but I cannot figure out how to make this formal. I tried proving that in fact all the disks, "stacked" together for the tubular neighborhood, gave a smooth $D\times [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$, but again I find it hard to make topological arguments when one step of the construction is "apply Schoenflies to get a disk". In particular, I can't prove the projection of this "solid neighborhood" to $D$ is continuous.

Does anyone know how to formalize this? Or, even better, a reference where this type of surgery is discussed? I checked a few places, but only found surgery on a single manifold, not the type discussed here, where we're surgering an embedded submanifold in some ambient manifold.